# Textbook Answer vs. My (and Symbolab's!) answer Solving the Derivative of a Polynomial

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

The book *Calculus in Five Hours* asks readers to solve the following [problem](https://books.google.com/books?id=epxLDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT46&lpg=PT46&dq=calculus+in+5+hours+144110&source=bl&ots=doEBh1b8FM&sig=ACfU3U1-7vwAEj4AXetT3AqH734t5FclPg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBwumShP7rAhVNtZ4KHU0FAFMQ6AEwGnoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=calculus%20in%205%20hours%20144110&f=false):

> Determine the derivative of the following polynomial:
> 5x<sup>7</sup> + 16x<sup>3</sup> - 9 at x=4.

I've done this problem a few times now and have come up with:

35 * 4<sup>6</sup> + 48 * 4<sup>2</sup> = 144,128.  [Symbolab agrees with me.](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/derivative-calculator/%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(5x%5E%7B7%7D%2B16x%5E%7B3%7D%E2%88%929%20%5Cright)%2C%20x%3D4) [Wolfram Alpha also agrees with me.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=evaluate+the+derivative+of+5x%5E7+%2B+16x%5E3+-+9+at+x%3D4)

But the book (link above) gives the answer 144,110, as does the (slightly buggy) calculator page to which it links.  Am I missing something? Can anyone see how the (incorrect) answer might have been determined?

Comment: I think you're correct

Comment: The calculator page to which the book links gave me $144100$; perhaps it gives only a few significant figures

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I pointed out in the question that it gives that answer.  ;-)

Comment: you're claiming then that 144110 = 144100?

Comment: I'd like to have this as an answer in case someone else uses this book to learn.  J.W.Tanner would you like to write it up?

Comment: Ok, I wrote an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  (One can tell from the last two digits that $144128$ is a multiple of $4$, as it should be, whereas $144110$ is not.)

The calculator page to which the book links gave me $144100$; perhaps it gave that rather than $144128$ because it gave only a few significant figures.

As far as why the book gives $144110$, I don't have a very satisfying explanation; it could be that $144100$ was intended but a typographical error was made -- that happens sometimes.

Comment: Thank you!  The calculator page also throws a number of errors.  It might just be out of date.